# Need to create the template by using the count of row entry

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm having input xml be like:

```
<row>
   <entry colname="col1" colsep="0" rowsep="0">Get</entry>
   <entry colname="col2" colsep="0" rowsep="0">Some</entry>
   <entry colname="col3" colsep="0" rowsep="0">Manual</entry>
</row>
<row>
   <entry colname="col1" colsep="0" rowsep="0">Skip</entry>
</row>
<row>
   <entry colname="col1" colsep="0" rowsep="0" namest="col1" nameend="col3">Temp</entry>
</row>
<row>
   <entry colname="col1" colsep="0" rowsep="0" namest="col1" nameend="col3">Task</entry>
</row>
```

XSL I have used like below:

```
<xsl:template match="row">
    <row>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </row>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entry">
    <entry>
        <xsl:attribute name="colname">
            <xsl:value-of select="@colname"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="colsep">
            <xsl:value-of select="@colsep"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="rowsep">
            <xsl:value-of select="@rowsep"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </entry>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entry[@colname and @namest and @nameend]">
        <entry>
            <xsl:attribute name="colname">
                <xsl:value-of select="@colname"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="colsep">
                <xsl:value-of select="@colsep"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="rowsep">
                <xsl:value-of select="@rowsep"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="namest">
                <xsl:value-of select="@namest"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="nameend">
                <xsl:value-of select="@nameend"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </entry>
    </xsl:template>
```

Expected output be like:

```
<row>
   <entry colname="col1" colsep="0" rowsep="0">Get</entry>
   <entry colname="col2" colsep="0" rowsep="0">Some</entry>
   <entry colname="col3" colsep="0" rowsep="0">Manual</entry>
</row>
<row>
   <entry colname="col1" colsep="0" rowsep="0">Skip</entry>
   <entry colname="col2" colsep="0" rowsep="0"/>
   <entry colname="col3" colsep="0" rowsep="0">
</row>
<row>
   <entry colname="col1" colsep="0" rowsep="0" namest="col1" nameend="col3">Temp</entry>
</row>
<row>
   <entry colname="col1" colsep="0" rowsep="0" namest="col1" nameend="col3">Task</entry>
</row>
```

There is having lot of entries with namest and nameend attribute. The Above entry template is working well for which having 3 entry inside the row. I want to create the new template for entry by using the count of entries inside the row. Please suggest.

Comment: The use case for `xsl:attribute` is dynamic attribute's name. Use [AVT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-attribute-value-template) instead: `<entry colname="{@colname}" colsep="{@colsep}" rowsep="{@rowsep}"><xsl:apply-templates/></entry>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can have a variable that stores the maximum number of `entry` elements in a `row`...

```
 <xsl:variable name="cols" select="max(//row[not(entry/@namest)]/count(entry))" />
```

Then, have a template that matches `row` elements that don't have the maximum number of `entry`, and use `xsl:for-each` to append new empty elements

```
<xsl:template match="row[not(entry[$cols])]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    <xsl:for-each select="count(entry) + 1 to $cols">
      <entry colname="col{.}" colsep="0" rowsep="0"></entry>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:variable name="cols" select="max(//row[not(entry/@namest)]/count(entry))" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row[not(entry[$cols]) and not(entry/@namest)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
      <xsl:for-each select="count(entry) + 1 to $cols">
        <entry colname="col{.}" colsep="0" rowsep="0"></entry>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'm having this type also in input: `<entry colname="col1" colsep="0" rowsep="0" namest="col1" nameend="col3">Temp</entry>` So It's creating empty entry for this type.

Comment: You really should amend your question if you actually want something different to what was asked. Thanks!

Comment: I got this error while Transformation `A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of substring-after() ("col1", "col1", ...)` for the `<xsl:variable name="start" select="xs:int(substring-after(//entry/@namest, 'col'))" />`

Comment: Have you got more than one `entry` element with a `namest` attribute on it? If so, can you edit your XML to show this case? Thanks!